# Make Input file required based on database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dynamic input file in laravel, input file will display based on data in database on select dropdown.  here is my database [image: loop_attachment table]

here is the explanation by code i have.

**ajax when select 2 dropdown which has id=groupid and id=lendertype:**

```
$('#groupid').on('change', function(){
    $.post('{{ URL::to('lender/dynamic') }}', {type: 'loop_attachment', id: $('#groupid').val(), key: $('#lendertype').val()}, function(e){
        $('#image').html('');
        $('#image').html(e);
        });
    });
$('#lendertype').on('change', function(){
    $.post('{{ URL::to('lender/dynamic') }}', {type: 'loop_attachment', id: $('#groupid').val(), key: $('#lendertype').val()}, function(e){
        $('#image').html('');
        $('#image').html(e);
        });
    });
```

**when select dropdown, input file will display in here :**

```
<div class="row" id="image">
</div>
```

**and here is my controller :**

```
public function postDynamic(Request $request) 
{        
    switch(Input::get('type')):
        case 'loop_attachment':
            $return = '';
            foreach(Loop_attachment::where('groupid', Input::get('id'))->where('type2', Input::get('key'))->where('active', 1)->get() as $row) 
                $return .= "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-6'><center><div class='form-group'><div class='btn btn-primary'><span>Upload $row->doctype</span> <input type='file' style='margin-bottom:1px;' class='form-control upload' name='image[]' id='image-$row->doctype'></div></div></center></div><div class='col-md-3'></div></div>";
            return $return;
        break;
    endswitch;       
}
```

Currently there are no errors or issues.
My question is, how to make input file become required if required column is 1 ?
please help me with the code.

I hope my explanation easy to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First change outer single quotes to double quotes. Here `'{{ URL::to('lender/dynamic') }}'`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it was done for what? because now all my code is already work. what I need is code how to make the required fields if required column = 1

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach you can write as:

```
  foreach(Loop_attachment::where('groupid', Input::get('id'))->where('type2', Input::get('key'))->where('active', 1)->get() as $row) {
      $required = $row->required ? 'required' : '';
      $return .= "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-6'><center><div class='form-group'><div class='btn btn-primary'><span>Upload $row->doctype</span> <input type='file' $required style='margin-bottom:1px;' class='form-control upload' name='image[]' id='image-$row->doctype'></div></div></center></div><div class='col-md-3'></div></div>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to customize the query executed by the validation rule, you may use the Rule class to fluently define the rule.You also specify the validation rules as an array instead of using the `|` character to delimit them:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($request, [
    'input_field_name' => [
        Rule::exists('table_name')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('required', 1);
        }),
    ],
]);
```

To know more about Laravel Validation visit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists